# HTTP Error 500.1013 - Internal Server Error IIS Node Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, iis-7, azure-app-service-plans, iisnode

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgEo.png)

While sending more than 240MB files in the HTTP Request body, We have an error 500.1013 and we have used the Azure App Service (Ubuntu) for hosting our application.

Comment: Have you tried to set system.webServer/iisnode maxRequestBufferSize or initalRequestBuffersize?

Comment: Yes, we have used below code <iisnode enableXFF="true" maxRequestBufferSize="52428800" loggingEnabled="true" />     <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097152000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>

Comment: Since IISnode just proxy request to node.exe. Is there any limit in node js itself?

Comment: We have set 2GB limit const apiProxy = proxy(
    config.get("apiBase"),
    {
      limit: "2gb",
      proxyReqPathResolver: req => "/" + (req.path.substring(`/${apiProxyPathPrefix}/`.length) + "?" + (url.parse(req.url).query || ''))
    });

Comment: i am having the same problem on Azure, any progress with this problem?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, did you resolve it?

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue, anybody resolve it? Please, let us know. :)